# Is there any existing cipher capable of scaling from a 1 bit key up to a one-time-pad?

Tags: symmetric, key-size

We have ciphers that handle small amounts of entropy, such as a 256 bit key for AES; and we have one time pads for enciphering 1:1 entropy, such as a 1GB key for a 1GB file if you could ever harvest enough decent random noise.

Now in theory you would imagine that there is a universal class or model of cipher that can scale smoothly from a single bit of entropy all the way upto a 1:1 one time pad.

***If such an algorithm or cipher already exists - what is it called?***

Comment: Three other regions along that continuum are [honey encryption](http://eprint.iacr.org/2014/155), [entropically-secure encryption](http://www.iacr.org/cryptodb/archive/2005/TCC/3646/3646.ps), and [encryption that remains information-theoretically secure against key-dependent messages](http://eprint.iacr.org/2007/333.pdf).

Comment: Note that the one-time-pad is not a cipher, by the modern definition, which requires key size to be fixed for arbitrary or much larger plaintext size. $\;$ I know no existing algorithm answering the question. It seems feasible to build one from existing primitives, but exactly **what would be the desired security criteria?**

Comment: @fgrieu I don't want to narrow the paradigm excessively; but I think the key criteria for genuinely scalable encryption is that an algorithm is honest in regards to information-theoretic security. If there is 1 bit of entropy then there are two (2^1) possible messages, if 2 bits then are 4 (2^2) possible messages, and so on.

Comment: The criteria that given ciphertext and $b$-bit key, $2^b$ distinct plaintexts are possible $\;$ a) Can not be reached at all for key/plaintext ratio above 1, even though that is considered in the question. $\;$ b) Is **NOT** enough to give a useful level of confidentiality for other ratio (proof: consider encryption by XOR with key padded with zeroes up to plaintext length); that criteria can however be a compatible addition to more standard security criteria, at least if we allow _about_ $2^b$ possible distinct plaintexts.

Comment: @fgrieu I'll drop the side note about key lengths above 1:1 as that's a logistical scenario rather than an algorithmic quality.

Comment: @fgrieu Once the implications of Shannon's work were absorbed in the 1950s, cryptographers strove for ciphers that wouldn't be breached once N bits of plaintext were known for an N bit key.

Comment: @fgrieu However, I'd like to step back a bit and ask: If we stay true to information-theoretic security, where we only have as much security against known plaintext attacks as the entropy we bring with us, what type of universal scaling encryption algorithm can exist? So the usual real world security criteria jump the gun in this regards, as we already have chained block ciphers that step-side entropy. Naturally the XOR boolean primitive isn't a scaling cipher as the key material is only applied to a subset of the plaintext.

Comment: I'm not a big fan of existence questions because proving that something doesn't exist is often hard.

Answer (score 1):

a one time pad ia very different from other fixed key ciphers.
A one time pad is just a xor(or modular addition) It does not miz anything or extend key and even a tiny bit of key reuse is very problematic.
We have stream ciphers which take a key and produce an infinite stream of pseudo random bits.

Perhaps what you are asking for is for a cipher with arbitrary key size with guranteed perfect security for total message length less than key size and reasonable security for reasonable key sizes.

I can suggest the following construct. take the key and duplicate it by concatenation to produce naive infinite key.
Use Each key block to encrypt a counter like in CTR mode.

This by itself doesn't give perfect secrecy. You could then xor each block with the following key block. That would give  perfect secrecy when message is at least one block less than key. It might be possible to do better. But this construct will give at least the security AES CTR.

Answer (score -1):

It's called a stream cipher, with re-keying.  If you consider a stream cipher as $ \operatorname{E}_k(m) $, simply set $ \frac{|k|}{|m|} $ to your desired ratio.    Then operate  and repetitively re-key when   $k$ is used up.  So a 256 bit key might encipher 1024 bits of message (0.25 ratio). You can even achieve 1:1 for information theoretic security à la one time pad.  It's not pretty and not very efficient, but works and is not  a million miles away from unsalted key stretching.  Clearly you wouldn't want the intrinsic delays of key stretching algorithms.    This re-keying (re-seeding) technique is common in many   RNG designs like Intel's RDRAND instructions, Raspberry Pi and similar to *nix's `/dev/urandom`,  etc.

This all works mathematically for any $k$ but remember that irrespective of the $ \frac{|k|}{|m|} $ ratio, $|k|$ should really be at least 128 bits.  So the cipher needs an internal state of at least 128 bits irrespective of the output length.  You risk brute force attacks against smaller re-keys even if the scaling works.  It may be honest in regards to information-theoretic security, but immediately leads to the question of why not simply have a conventionally small $ \frac{|k|}{|m|} $ ratio? I'll leave that hanging...

But just to address *"if you could ever harvest enough decent random noise"* for 2019:  You can generate 1GB of entropy in less than 10 minutes with a €3000 commercial TRNG, and as much and as fast as you can write to any SSD with a laboratory TRNG.

Comment: A 256-bit key used to encrypt 256 bits of ciphertext through a stream cipher does _not_ necessarily preserve information theoretic security! Your "ratio" calculations are **incorrect and baseless.**

Comment: @forest **Oh- no they're not.**

Comment: Let's remember to keep comments productive and use them for their intended purpose - if you don't have an objective response to criticism, then don't post anything.

Answer (score -2):

I call an algorithm meeting this spec "rolling xor". It's only strong at the one-time-pad level though.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: It is no more or less of an answer than the one that was upvoted.

Comment: Yeah, that other one isn't very good either.

Answer (score -2):

Vigenere matches the description, though its security problems when the key is shorter than the message are well known.

Answer (score -2):

Fix a $b$-bit string $k_0$ chosen uniformly at random.  Let $k = \operatorname{SHAKE128-256}(k_0)$.  Use $k$ as a key for a standard symmetric cryptosystem with a 128-bit security level, like AES-256-GCM.

The number $b$, up to 256, determines the minimum expected cost of an attack on this cryptosystem: ${\sim}2^b$, or ${\sim}2^b/t$ in a multi-target attack on the first of $t$ targets.  You can set $b = 1$, and you get essentially no security; or you can set $b = 256$, and you get a 128-bit security level, which is more than humanity has the capacity to break; or you can set it anywhere in between to ‘smoothly’ scale the security.

But you should really just set it to 256, because why would you want anything less than a 128-bit security level if, as the omission of a budget in your answer suggests, you are unconstrained by cost?

Comment: SHAKE-128/256 use 1600-bit Keccak internally, therefore it cannot scale all the way up to OTP.

Comment: There's no meaning to a security level above 256 bits.  I'm answering this question in practical terms, not in fantasy terms.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but since when did AES-256-GCM have a 128-bit security level? I was under the impression that the random nonce defeated multi-target attacks.

Comment: @forest I generally recommend sequential nonces so you don't have to worry about collisions and can _guarantee_ incorrect implementations will be immediately detected, and I generally recommend 256-bit keys so that you don't have to think about whether multi-target attacks _might_ be relevant.

Comment: Thanks, that makes more sense. I've added my +1.